# DEVEXPRESS MVVM: managing tabs in a DocumentGroup

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls, devexpress

I'm working with the MVVM pattern, with C# in VS2013.

I have a DocumentGroup in my project and a group of user control (xaml files) in a directory of my project.

```
<dxd:DocumentGroup Name="documentcontainer" ItemHeight="3*" SelectedTabIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding tabsCollection}" AllowMove="False" AllowFloat="False" AllowDrag="False">

</dxd:DocumentGroup>
```

Im my viewModel there is the define of tabsCollection:

```
    private ObservableCollection<DocumentPanel> p_tabsCollection;
    public ObservableCollection<DocumentPanel> tabsCollection
    {
        get { return p_tabsCollection; }
        set
        {
            p_tabsCollection = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("tabsCollection");
        }

    }

    private void Initialize() {
        DocumentPanel t = new DocumentPanel( );
        t.Content = Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("View/UC/ucImpianti.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); ;
        p_tabsCollection.Add(t);
    }
```

1. is the type of tabsCollection correct?
2. how can I insert my user control (xaml file) in the documentPanel? (if the type is correct)

I want create some tabs populated with the user control. From my menu, different voices must open different "usercontrol in tabs", so at the start-time there is no tabs: they are created at runtime, when user clicks on the menu.

UPDATED CODE: now it seems correct, but it generates an error/exception when starts..

---

**UPDATE-->SOLUTION**

In this way it works:

```
<dxd:DocumentGroup Name="documentcontainer" ItemHeight="3*" ItemsSource="{Binding tabsCollection}" AllowDrag="False" AllowMove="False" AllowSplitters="False" AllowSizing="False" AllowFloat="False" ClosingBehavior="ImmediatelyRemove" SelectedTabIndex="{Binding SelectedDocumentIndex}" >
    <dxd:DocumentGroup.ItemStyle>
        <Style TargetType="dxd:DocumentPanel">
            <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding CloseCommand}" />
        </Style>
    </dxd:DocumentGroup.ItemStyle>
</dxd:DocumentGroup>
```

While CloseCommand is the same I posted when I asked this question. The key-to-solution was in the xaml.

Comment: The code seems to be correct, what kind of error occurs?

Comment: @PaulO now I can open the tab like I want, but I have 3 troubles:
1) when I want close the tab, the app crashes
2) the content of the usercontrol is bigger than the documentgroup. How can I insert a scroll?
3) I have a set of usercontrols; only one for every type must be open in the same time, if I open again an already opened tab, the focus goes to the one already open. How?

ps. I hope the point 3) is clear.

Comment: 1) when the DocumentGroup.ItemsSource property is used, the panel can be removed only via the ItemsSource collection. Create a custom command in your view model and bind the DocumentPanel.CloseCommand to this custom command. In the command, you can change your item source as required. 2) you can just add the ScrollViewer control to your usercontrol. 3) you can set the DocumentPanel.IsActive property for the existing panel

Comment: Hi, please never include "solved" in your title. The green checkmark is enough. Also, please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: Actually, you should also move your solution to an answer of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your data-collection to the [DockLayoutManager.ItemsSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ItemsSourcetopic) property as shown in the [MVVM Support - Building Dock UI](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11386) help article. To visualize elements of the ItemsSource collection as layout items, provide templates via the [ItemTemplate](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ItemTemplatetopic) or [ItemTemplateSelector](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ItemTemplateSelectortopic) property.

Comment: can I bind the itemsource directly to the documentgroup?

Comment: Yes, you can use the DocumentGroup.ItemsSource property. However the docking functionality for this group will not work. You need to disable the AllowMove, AllowFloat, and AllowDrag properties for those panels that are created to represent items in the item source, otherwise the InvalidOperationException will be thrown.

Comment: Now in my xaml I have ItemsSource="{Binding tabsCollection}". tabsCollection is defined in the viewmodel like a ObservableCollection<DocumentPanel>. is it right? Because I can't see anything when I run the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read the following article that described how to use the DevExpress MVVM Framework and the  TabbedDocumentUIService implementation that provides methods to create and show documents as tabs:  [DevExpress MVVM Framework. Interaction of ViewModels. IDocumentManagerService.](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2013/10/09/devexpress-mvvm-framework-interaction-of-viewmodels-idocumentmanagerservice.aspx)

Below is the main idea:

```
<Button Content="Show Document" 
    Command="{Binding ShowDocumentCommand}" CommandParameter="Document1" />
...
<dxdo:DockLayoutManager>
    <dxdo:LayoutGroup Orientation="Vertical">
        <dxdo:DocumentGroup Caption="Documents">
            <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <dxdo:TabbedDocumentUIService />
            </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </dxdo:DocumentGroup>
    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
</dxdo:DockLayoutManager>


[POCOViewModel]
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    [ServiceProperty]
    protected virtual IDocumentManagerService DocumentManager { 
        get { return null; } 
    }
    [Command]
    public void ShowDocument(string document) {
        IDocument doc = DocumentManager.CreateDocument(document, null, this);
        doc.Title = document;
        doc.Show();
    }
}
```

The complete code example is available in the DevExpress Code Examples database at http://www.devexpress.com/example=E4861.

Related step-by-step tutorial series about the building a fully-functional and well-organized MVVM application in a few clicks: [Scaffolding Wizards - Getting Started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15282)

Comment: it isn't a clear example for a newbie like me, I've already seen that article... are there other article like that?